# Ansible playbook with nested python scripts

Tags: python-2.7, module, ansible, ansible-2.x

I am trying to execute a ansible playbook which uses the script module to run a custom python script.
This custom python script is importing another python script. 
On execution of the playbook the ansible command fails while trying to import the util script. I am new to ansible, please help!!

**helloWorld.yaml:**

```
- hosts: all
  tasks:
  - name: Create a directory
    script: /ansible/ems/ansible-mw-tube/modules/createdirectory.py "{{arg1}}"
```

**createdirectory.py** -- Script configured in YAML playbook

```
#!/bin/python

import sys
import os
from hello import HelloWorld


class CreateDir:
        def create(self, dirName,HelloWorldContext):
                output=HelloWorld.createFolder(HelloWorldContext,dirName)
                print output
                return output
def main(dirName, HelloWorldContext):
        c = CreateDir()
        c.create(dirName, HelloWorldContext)
if __name__ == "__main__":
        HelloWorldContext = HelloWorld()
        main(sys.argv[1],HelloWorldContext)
        HelloWorldContext = HelloWorld()
```

**hello.py** -- util script which is imported in the main script written above

```
#!/bin/python

import os
import sys

class HelloWorld:

         def createFolder(self, dirName):
             print dirName
             if not os.path.exists(dirName):
                os.makedirs(dirName)
                print dirName
                if os.path.exists(dirName):
                   return "sucess"
                else:
                   return "failure"
```

**Ansible executable command**

```
ansible-playbook -v -i /ansible/ems/ansible-mw-tube/inventory/helloworld_host /ansible/ems/ansible-mw-tube/playbooks/helloWorld.yml -e "arg1=/opt/logs/helloworld"
```

**Ansible version**

```
ansible --version
[WARNING]: log file at /opt/ansible/ansible.log is not writeable and we cannot create it, aborting

ansible 2.2.0.0
  config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = Default w/o overrides
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `script` module copies the script to the remote server and executes it there using the `shell` command. It can't find the util script, since it doesn't transfer that file - it doesn't know that it needs to do it.

You have several options, such as use `copy` to move both files to the server and use `shell` to execute them. But since what you seem to be doing is creating a directory, the `file` module can do that for you with no scripts necessary.